# Floating divs trying to keep responsive

Tags: html, css

```css
#body {
    background-color: rgba(51, 5, 22, 0.5);
    padding: 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#category, #mission {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:bolder;
    float: left;
}
#mission {
    margin-left: 8em;
}
.category-picked, .mission-picked {
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!-- BODY SECTION START !-->
    <div id="body">
        <div id="category">
            <div class="category-header">
                Category
            </div>
             <div class="category-picked">
                Random Picked Oneeeeeee
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mission">
            <div class="mission-header">
                Mission 
            </div>
            <div class="mission-picked">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis metus nibh, placerat vitae vehicula eu, lobortis id eros. Nam ac ipsum enim. Cras in elit sed ligula accumsan venenatis. Fusce interdum, nibh eleifend ullamcorper gravida, enim augue tristique orci, a fringilla mi velit sed erat. Sed nulla augue, tempus eu nisl a, tincidunt egestas magna. Mauris non nulla tempus, tincidunt nibh at, scelerisque velit. Mauris vulputate ut odio id ultrices. Fusce et pulvinar metus. Nullam suscipit accumsan libero eu fringilla. Curabitur vulputate eu metus quis dapibus. Etiam dapibus mi eu mi lacinia, id facilisis orci dapibus. Donec vel nisi hendrerit, facilisis quam interdum, facilisis dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BODY SECTION END !-->
```

I'm trying to make a seperated divs but must be stay inline.
I try to avoid to use `table` and give my divs a `width` to make them stay responsive.

As you see the divs pushing each other away i want to make them stay inline like whenever the text is short. How do I need to do this ?

I also fiddle it 
https://jsfiddle.net/63s8hadd/

Comment: You'll have to set width on the divs...using percentages,,and adjust them in media queries ...but it's not clear how this is supposed to look.

Comment: What's wrong with `display:table`? https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/5t253yvx/

Comment: @Aziz that does the trick for me thanks, i was talking about the html `table` didn't know about this one!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

```css
#body {
    background-color: rgba(51, 5, 22, 0.5);
    padding: 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#category, #mission {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:bolder;
    /*float: left;*/
}
#mission {
    /*margin-left: 8em; Why? */
}
.category-picked, .mission-picked {
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.table{
  display: table;
}
.tr{
  display: table-row;
  }
.td{
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<!-- BODY SECTION START !-->
    <div id="body" class="table">
        <div id="category" class="tr">
            <div class="category-header td">
                Category
            </div>
             <div class="category-picked td">
                Random Picked Oneeeeeee
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mission" class="tr">
            <div class="mission-header td">
                Mission 
            </div>
            <div class="mission-picked td">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis metus nibh, placerat vitae vehicula eu, lobortis id eros. Nam ac ipsum enim. Cras in elit sed ligula accumsan venenatis. Fusce interdum, nibh eleifend ullamcorper gravida, enim augue tristique orci, a fringilla mi velit sed erat. Sed nulla augue, tempus eu nisl a, tincidunt egestas magna. Mauris non nulla tempus, tincidunt nibh at, scelerisque velit. Mauris vulputate ut odio id ultrices. Fusce et pulvinar metus. Nullam suscipit accumsan libero eu fringilla. Curabitur vulputate eu metus quis dapibus. Etiam dapibus mi eu mi lacinia, id facilisis orci dapibus. Donec vel nisi hendrerit, facilisis quam interdum, facilisis dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BODY SECTION END !-->
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/63s8hadd/1/

> Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption",
>   "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", and
>   "table-row-group" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a
>   !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

ref:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp